# How to merge strings that have substrings in common to produce some groups in a data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, distance, similarity

I have a sample data:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'ACTIVITY':['b,c','a','a,c,d,e','f,g,h,i','j,k,l','k,l,m']})
```

What I want to do is merge some strings if they have sub strings in common. So, in this example, the strings 'b,c','a','a,c,d,e' should be merged together because they can be linked to each other. 'j,k,l' and 'k,l,m' should be in one group. In the end, I hope I can have something like:

```
               group
'b,c',         0
'a',           0
'a,c,d,e',     0
'f,g,h,i',     1
'j,k,l',       2
'k,l,m'        2
```

So, I can have three groups and there is no common sub strings between any two groups.

Now, I am trying to build up a similarity data frame, in which 1 means two strings have sub strings in common. Here is my code:

```
commonWords=1

for i in np.arange(a.shape[0]):
    a.loc[:,a.loc[i,'ACTIVITY']]=0

for i in a.loc[:,'ACTIVITY']:
    il=i.split(',')
    for j in a.loc[:,'ACTIVITY']:
        jl=j.split(',')
        c=[x in il for x in jl]
        c1=[x for x in c if x==True]
        a.loc[(a.loc[:,'ACTIVITY']==i),j]=1 if len(c1)>=commonWords else 0
    
a
```

The result is:

```
    ACTIVITY    b,c     a   a,c,d,e     f,g,h,i     j,k,l   k,l,m
0   b,c          1      0       1           0       0       0
1   a            0      1       1           0       0       0
2   a,c,d,e      1      1       1           0       0       0
3   f,g,h,i      0      0       0           1       0       0
4   j,k,l        0      0       0           0       1       1
5   k,l,m        0      0       0           0       1       1
```

From here, you can see if there is 1, then the related row and columns should be merged together.

Comment: Doesn't this look like a graph problem (connected components)? You may want to look into networkx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `networkx` with [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html):

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'ACTIVITY':['b,c','a','a,c,d,e','f,g,h,i','j,k,l','k,l,m']})

import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations, chain

#split values by , to lists
splitted = a['ACTIVITY'].str.split(',')

#create edges (can only connect two nodes)
L2_nested = [list(combinations(l,2)) for l in splitted]
L2 = list(chain.from_iterable(L2_nested))
print (L2)
[('b', 'c'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), 
 ('c', 'e'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('f', 'h'), ('f', 'i'), 
 ('g', 'h'), ('g', 'i'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'k'), ('j', 'l'), 
 ('k', 'l'), ('k', 'l'), ('k', 'm'), ('l', 'm')]
```

---

```
#create the graph from the lists
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(L2)
connected_comp = nx.connected_components(G)

#create dict for common values
node2id = {x: cid for cid, c in enumerate(connected_comp) for x in c}

# create groups by mapping first value of series called splitted
a['group'] = [node2id.get(x[0]) for x in splitted]
print (a)
  ACTIVITY  group
0      b,c      0
1        a      0
2  a,c,d,e      0
3  f,g,h,i      1
4    j,k,l      2
5    k,l,m      2
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Just one more thing to ask: what if I want to specify the number of common words. For example, I want to merge two strings if there are 2 or 3, or.. substrings in common between them. Can I change somewhere in this code to do that? Thanks

Comment: @FengChen - It is more complicated, need some time. Maybe is possible edit question e.g. for 3 common words, what is expected output?

Comment: Hi, I just posted the questioin here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632874/how-to-merge-strings-that-have-certain-number-of-substrings-in-common-to-produce. Could you please take a look? Thanks